# DataGrid like template for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Currently I am developing a windows store app for which I need to develop a control which looks like standard .NET DataGrid. Here I am attaching the screen shot of the UI which I am trying to achieve in windows store app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With WP8, since there is no Datagrid, you could use Listview or Implement something like below,

[`How to get a data grid like UI`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikezh/archive/2012/07/26/windows-8-metro-app-how-to-get-a-data-grid-like-ui-for-a-collection-of-items.aspx)